# Operator overloading in Isabelle

Tags: proof, isabelle

I want to use the nat type in Isabelle but I want to overload some existing definitions like for example addition. I wrote the following code:

```
theory Prueba
imports Main HOL
begin

primrec suma::"nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat" where
"suma 0 n = 0" |
"suma (Suc x) n = 0"
no_notation suma (infix "+" 65)

value "2 + (1 :: nat)"
```

I tried to overload addition with a new definition that always outputs 0. However when I evaluate `2 + (1 :: nat)` I get `"Suc (Suc (Suc 0))" :: "nat"`, which means Isabelle is still using the plus definition from Nat. How can I get it to use my new definition of +?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your must use `no_notation` to remove the default plus-syntax which comes from the `plus` type class of the `Groups` theory.

```
no_notation Groups.plus_class.plus (infixl "+" 65)
```

Then you can use

```
notation suma (infixl "+" 65)
```

to add your own syntax.

(I have never tried to override such basic parts of the definitions. I guess it might lead to strange situations – especially for other people trying to work with your theory afterwards.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I do that I then get an error when trying to specify a lemma about plus, like: `lemma suma_0: "∀m::nat. m + 0 = m"`, gives a Inner syntax error.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem here. Are you sure that you added the `notation suma (infixl "+" 65)` line at the right place?

Comment: (Just changed my answer to use your function name `suma` instead of `plus`.)

Comment: @Ben_Keks Indeed. I placed the line just after my `suma` definition. I am using Isabelle2015 IDE. When I put your line whenever I write the `+` sign I get an inner syntax error `Failed to parse term`

Comment: The following code works on my Isabelle2015.
`primrec suma::"nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat" where
"suma 0 n = 0" |
"suma (Suc x) n = 0"

no_notation Groups.plus_class.plus (infixl "+" 65)
notation suma (infixl "+" 65)

value "2 + (1 :: nat)"

lemma suma_0: "∀m::nat. m + 0 = m"
oops`

Comment: @Ben_Keks How can I overload the "<" and "<=" symbols? What Group do I need to reference?

Comment: @Ben_Keks, I tried with `no_notation Orderings.ord_class.less (infixl "<" 50) `, but I still get an `Ambiguous input` error when I try to use `<`

Comment: @MartinCopes It usually works when you copy the precedence-information from the [declaration site](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2013/dist/library/HOL/Orderings.html) literally. So in this case, this would read `no_notation Orderings.ord_class.less ("(_/ < _)"  [51, 51] 50)`.